# Windows server backup: adding more destination?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using Windows 2008R2 configured with windows backup using a dedicated hard disk: http://grab.by/CPhm and http://grab.by/CPhq .

Can I add a second destination (a shared folder) to have two backups every night? If I try I have this alert http://grab.by/CPhC and so it seems I don't have any chance.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple batch file that can be setup as a scheduled task to copy the completed backup to another location.